# LINQ - left join to find unmatched records

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to execute a left join between 2 datatables that will return all records from the left table without a corresponding value in the right table on the join criteria. As of now I have the following which returns nothing:

```
Dim Query1 = From exasset In dtExistingAssets _
             GroupJoin asset In dtNewAssets _
             On exasset("ACCOUNT_NAME") Equals asset("ACCOUNT_NAME") _
             Into results = Group _
             From f In results.DefaultIfEmpty _
             Where IsDBNull(f) _
             SelectNewWith _
             { //...
```

I've seen several references to using `Any` but I wasn't able get the syntax correct. Can anyone please help out? This is something that is really simple to accomplish in SQL but seems a lot more complicated in *LINQ*.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `IsDBNull(f)`, a left join will result in a null value (`Nothing` in VB) not a `DBNull` value. I think you should change it to: ``

```
...
From f In results.DefaultIfEmpty _
Where f is Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the strongly typed `DataRow` extension methods like [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) which also support nullables.

```
Dim query = From exAsset In dtExistingAssets
        Group Join newAsset In dtNewAssets
        On exAsset.Field(Of String)("ACCOUNT_NAME") Equals newAsset.Field(Of String)("ACCOUNT_NAME") Into Group
        From joinedAssets In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
        Where joinedAssets.Field(Of String)("ACCOUNT_NAME") Is Nothing
```

If you just want to know the new accounts, you can also use the efficient [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
Dim existingAccounts = From exRow In dtExistingAssets
                       Select exRow.Field(Of String)("ACCOUNT_NAME")
Dim newAccounts = From newRow In dtNewAssets
                       Select newRow.Field(Of String)("ACCOUNT_NAME")
Dim newAccNotInExisting = newAccounts.Except( existingAccounts )
```